# Class 'Cmgmyr\Messenger\MessengerServiceProvider::class' not found

Tags: laravel

In my laravel project, I need messaging system. I trying to install "cmgmyr/laravel-messenger" and getting this error

`"Class 'Cmgmyr\Messenger\MessengerServiceProvider::class' not found"`

when i execute this command

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Cmgmyr\Messenger\MessengerServiceProvider"`

any suggestion to resolve this problem.

Comment: make sure the package is installed correctly and you have also put  `Cmgmyr\Messenger\MessengerServiceProvider::class` in you app.php providers array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely is that you have not installed the required dependency. Once you have added the dependency to your `composer.json` remember to run `composer install`.

To make this process really easy for yourself instead of adding the dependency to `composer.json` you can run `composer require cmgmyr/laravel-messenger`. This will add the latest version to your composer file and install the dependency for you.